# IE emitting expired cookie which results to not being able to access my web app

Tags: session-cookies, internet-explorer-11

These are the deatils:

```
-Server UTC 00:00. 
-Client UTC +08:00
-Sessiontimeout 30 mins.
```

Here's what happened. Im testing the web app that I made using different browsers, let's focus on firefox and IE11 and safari. The app that I'm working on loads successfully on those firefox except on IE and safari.

These are the cookies for each browser:

```
1) IE11 
   Received -http-session-  6::http.session::f6733f3fa5207e3cd4cb2f5923cb0997   Tue, 30 Jun 2015 09:50:26 GMT   1.1.03.125  /   No  Yes

2) Firefox
   -http-session-=7::http.session::31f262d8be7e89959da30fa4feed7076; expires=Tue, 30 Jun 2015 10:51:49 GMT; path=/; domain=1.1.03.125; HttpOnly


3) Safari (for windows)
   http-session-=9::http.session::f06cb8c5b9ccf6f910c78f18f2989b37; path=/; domain=1.1.03.125; expires=Tue, 30 Jun 2015 10:01:12 GMT; httponly
```

While the server time is

```
Local Time: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 18:19:55 +0900
UTC Time:   Tue, 30 Jun 2015 09:19:55 +0000
```

Using firefox as my baseline, IE11 and safari uses expired cookie, and that is why I could not get pass the login page. The question is why is IE11 doing it? is it a known issue? what about safari? What can I do to correct the value of "expires"?

Note: I thought that the problem has something to do with IE11 not being able to handle max-age. But then I realized that the article that I'm reading was made years ago.

Comment: You need to provide additional information about the problem you are having which appears to be that "the app" is not loading in IE. What is the app? Why do you think it has to do with max-age? It appears that others are not having a problem with IE11 and max-age of cookies http://promincproductions.com/blog/set-cookie-expiration-date-browser-compatiability/

Comment: Hi @RichardChambers I added details to my post. Please enlighten me thanks :{

Comment: I do not see any information about "the app" as in server environment, scripting language and environment, nor how functionality is apportioned between client and server.  Not sure what you mean by "loads successfully" either so a more detailed description about the behavior difference between Firefox and IE would be helpful.